# Proper routing in AngularJS and C# MVC

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

So I have an app that uses C# MVC and AngularJS 1.5. I am using angular-ui-router for frontend routing. I'm having problem with routing cause I think the code `<div ui-view></div>` doesn't work inside /Shared/_Layout.cshtml. Also when I navigate through other pages the _Layout.cshtml gets rendered twice.

Here's my route config:

```
routes.MapRoute(
   name: "Default",
   url: "{*url}",
   defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }    
);
```

Then my _Layout.cshtml contains all the skeleton html needed like the styles and scripts import also including the `<div ui-view></div>`

Then here's my main route in Angular:

```
$stateProvider.state('main', {
        url: '/',
        views: {
            '': {
                templateUrl: '/Home/Home'                    
            },
            'sidenav': {
                templateUrl: '/Partials/SideNav',
            }
        }
    })
```

Comment: If you provide a name for ui-view, it should have matching state.

Comment: Sorry my bad, my ui-view in _Layout doesn't have a name that's why in my routing there's no name for it. But the problem still persists.

Comment: routes look dodgy